# Draw path in Canvas with SVG Path data (SVG paths to Canvas paths)

Tags: html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I have a detailed map of a country in SVG with is separated in areas in this format:

```
<path class="state-x-area"
      d="m 575.8672,180.4954 c -0.6572,-0.0938 -2.252,-0.4688 -2.627,-0.375 -1.0313,0.1875 0.375,1.501 -0.1875,1.876 -0.4688,0.1875 -1.0313,-0.0938 -1.501,0.0938 -0.1875,0.0938 0.0938,0.4688 -0.0938,0.6572 -0.9375,0.75 -2.4385,0.8438 -3.377,1.6875 -1.125,1.0322 2.0635,3.6582 0.6572,4.6904 -3.2832,2.3447 -1.2197,-1.5947 -3.377,1.501 -0.2813,0.375 0.8438,0.4688 1.0313,0.9375 0.1875,0.376 -0.9375,0.2822 -0.9375,0.6572 0,0.1875 0.9375,1.4072 0.5625,1.876 -1.0313,1.0313 -2.5322,-0.5635 -3.4707,-0.5635 -1.4063,0 1.3135,1.3135 -1.0313,0.6572 -0.6572,-0.1875 -1.501,-1.2197 -1.7822,-1.7822 -0.1875,-0.1875 -0.376,-0.751 -0.4697,-0.5625 -0.375,0.5625 -0.2813,1.2188 -0.6563,1.6875 -1.2188,1.5947 -2.9082,0 -4.3145,0.4697 -0.1875,0.0938 0.1875,0.4688 0,0.6563 -0.8447,0.4688 -2.5332,0.375 -3.377,0 0,0 0,-0.0938 0.0938,-0.0938 0.4688,-0.4688 1.0313,-0.9375 1.2197,-1.4072 3.2822,0.1875 -0.4697,-2.0635 -1.4072,-2.626 -0.6563,-0.375 0.375,-1.5947 0.1875,-2.0635 -0.1875,-0.4697 -1.6885,0.8438 -1.3135,-0.376 0.2813,-0.8438 2.0635,-1.5938 1.4072,-2.1572 -0.4688,-0.375 -2.627,-0.1875 -2.4385,-1.3125 0.1875,-1.501 2.5322,-1.126 2.7197,-3.002 -0.0938,0 -0.0938,0 -0.1875,0 0.5625,0.0938 1.126,0.1875 1.7822,0.2813 0.75,0.0938 1.501,0.6563 2.251,0.75 0.751,0.0938 1.501,-0.4688 2.252,-0.375 0.4688,0.0938 0.75,0.751 1.2188,0.751 0.1875,0.0938 0.0938,-0.4697 0.2813,-0.5635 0.4697,-0.4688 1.2197,-0.6563 1.6885,-1.2188 0.376,-0.2822 0.0938,-0.9385 0.376,-1.2197 1.7813,-1.4072 3.6582,0.375 5.3457,-0.375 0.5635,-0.2813 0.6572,-1.126 1.2197,-1.3135 0.0938,-0.0938 3.1895,0.375 3.2832,0.2813 0.2813,-0.0938 -0.2813,-0.4688 -0.375,-0.75 -0.2813,-1.501 0.8438,-1.876 2.251,-1.876 0.3752,0 1.1262,2.9072 3.0959,4.502 l 0,0 z"
      style="fill:#000;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1" />
```

(And I have many of such paths.)

Now I need that all done via Canvas (because of a redesign and a totally new task which need to be done with that).
I saw that it is possible to draw paths in Canvas but could I do that with such SVG paths?

Comment: This seems to do the trick: http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/

Comment: For the www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/ provided by Zevan, you could save that with `getImageData` then `putImageData` to reuse and move it wherever you want.

Answer (score 52):

In Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge you could make use of the Path2D API to draw Paths in Canvas based on SVG path data. The Path2D constructor can optionally take a SVG path data as its input and generate the equivalent path on Canvas.

This API is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/path2d) by Internet Explorer, Android Browser or Opera Mini. So, if you need to support those browsers then you have to convert the SVG path into the equivalent Canvas commands using any one of the converters and then put it to use.

**Path on Canvas using Path2D API:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000'

  var p = new Path2D("m 75.8672,80.4954 c -0.6572,-0.0938 -2.252,-0.4688 -2.627,-0.375 -1.0313,0.1875 0.375,1.501 -0.1875,1.876 -0.4688,0.1875 -1.0313,-0.0938 -1.501,0.0938 -0.1875,0.0938 0.0938,0.4688 -0.0938,0.6572 -0.9375,0.75 -2.4385,0.8438 -3.377,1.6875 -1.125,1.0322 2.0635,3.6582 0.6572,4.6904 -3.2832,2.3447 -1.2197,-1.5947 -3.377,1.501 -0.2813,0.375 0.8438,0.4688 1.0313,0.9375 0.1875,0.376 -0.9375,0.2822 -0.9375,0.6572 0,0.1875 0.9375,1.4072 0.5625,1.876 -1.0313,1.0313 -2.5322,-0.5635 -3.4707,-0.5635 -1.4063,0 1.3135,1.3135 -1.0313,0.6572 -0.6572,-0.1875 -1.501,-1.2197 -1.7822,-1.7822 -0.1875,-0.1875 -0.376,-0.751 -0.4697,-0.5625 -0.375,0.5625 -0.2813,1.2188 -0.6563,1.6875 -1.2188,1.5947 -2.9082,0 -4.3145,0.4697 -0.1875,0.0938 0.1875,0.4688 0,0.6563 -0.8447,0.4688 -2.5332,0.375 -3.377,0 0,0 0,-0.0938 0.0938,-0.0938 0.4688,-0.4688 1.0313,-0.9375 1.2197,-1.4072 3.2822,0.1875 -0.4697,-2.0635 -1.4072,-2.626 -0.6563,-0.375 0.375,-1.5947 0.1875,-2.0635 -0.1875,-0.4697 -1.6885,0.8438 -1.3135,-0.376 0.2813,-0.8438 2.0635,-1.5938 1.4072,-2.1572 -0.4688,-0.375 -2.627,-0.1875 -2.4385,-1.3125 0.1875,-1.501 2.5322,-1.126 2.7197,-3.002 -0.0938,0 -0.0938,0 -0.1875,0 0.5625,0.0938 1.126,0.1875 1.7822,0.2813 0.75,0.0938 1.501,0.6563 2.251,0.75 0.751,0.0938 1.501,-0.4688 2.252,-0.375 0.4688,0.0938 0.75,0.751 1.2188,0.751 0.1875,0.0938 0.0938,-0.4697 0.2813,-0.5635 0.4697,-0.4688 1.2197,-0.6563 1.6885,-1.2188 0.376,-0.2822 0.0938,-0.9385 0.376,-1.2197 1.7813,-1.4072 3.6582,0.375 5.3457,-0.375 0.5635,-0.2813 0.6572,-1.126 1.2197,-1.3135 0.0938,-0.0938 3.1895,0.375 3.2832,0.2813 0.2813,-0.0938 -0.2813,-0.4688 -0.375,-0.75 -0.2813,-1.501 0.8438,-1.876 2.251,-1.876 0.3752,0 1.1262,2.9072 3.0959,4.502 l 0,0 z");
  ctx.stroke(p);
  ctx.fill(p);
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' height='600px' width='600px'></canvas>
```

**SVG Output:** (for comparison)

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 600 600' height='600px' width='600px'>
  <path class="state-x-area" d="m 75.8672,80.4954 c -0.6572,-0.0938 -2.252,-0.4688 -2.627,-0.375 -1.0313,0.1875 0.375,1.501 -0.1875,1.876 -0.4688,0.1875 -1.0313,-0.0938 -1.501,0.0938 -0.1875,0.0938 0.0938,0.4688 -0.0938,0.6572 -0.9375,0.75 -2.4385,0.8438 -3.377,1.6875 -1.125,1.0322 2.0635,3.6582 0.6572,4.6904 -3.2832,2.3447 -1.2197,-1.5947 -3.377,1.501 -0.2813,0.375 0.8438,0.4688 1.0313,0.9375 0.1875,0.376 -0.9375,0.2822 -0.9375,0.6572 0,0.1875 0.9375,1.4072 0.5625,1.876 -1.0313,1.0313 -2.5322,-0.5635 -3.4707,-0.5635 -1.4063,0 1.3135,1.3135 -1.0313,0.6572 -0.6572,-0.1875 -1.501,-1.2197 -1.7822,-1.7822 -0.1875,-0.1875 -0.376,-0.751 -0.4697,-0.5625 -0.375,0.5625 -0.2813,1.2188 -0.6563,1.6875 -1.2188,1.5947 -2.9082,0 -4.3145,0.4697 -0.1875,0.0938 0.1875,0.4688 0,0.6563 -0.8447,0.4688 -2.5332,0.375 -3.377,0 0,0 0,-0.0938 0.0938,-0.0938 0.4688,-0.4688 1.0313,-0.9375 1.2197,-1.4072 3.2822,0.1875 -0.4697,-2.0635 -1.4072,-2.626 -0.6563,-0.375 0.375,-1.5947 0.1875,-2.0635 -0.1875,-0.4697 -1.6885,0.8438 -1.3135,-0.376 0.2813,-0.8438 2.0635,-1.5938 1.4072,-2.1572 -0.4688,-0.375 -2.627,-0.1875 -2.4385,-1.3125 0.1875,-1.501 2.5322,-1.126 2.7197,-3.002 -0.0938,0 -0.0938,0 -0.1875,0 0.5625,0.0938 1.126,0.1875 1.7822,0.2813 0.75,0.0938 1.501,0.6563 2.251,0.75 0.751,0.0938 1.501,-0.4688 2.252,-0.375 0.4688,0.0938 0.75,0.751 1.2188,0.751 0.1875,0.0938 0.0938,-0.4697 0.2813,-0.5635 0.4697,-0.4688 1.2197,-0.6563 1.6885,-1.2188 0.376,-0.2822 0.0938,-0.9385 0.376,-1.2197 1.7813,-1.4072 3.6582,0.375 5.3457,-0.375 0.5635,-0.2813 0.6572,-1.126 1.2197,-1.3135 0.0938,-0.0938 3.1895,0.375 3.2832,0.2813 0.2813,-0.0938 -0.2813,-0.4688 -0.375,-0.75 -0.2813,-1.501 0.8438,-1.876 2.251,-1.876 0.3752,0 1.1262,2.9072 3.0959,4.502 l 0,0 z"
  style="fill:#000;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

<sup>**Note:** I have modified the `moveTo` command coordinates in both the SVG and Canvas path to make the output more visible without switching to full screen mode.</sup>

---

**References:**

- [Drawing shapes on Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes)
- [Path2D API - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D)