# How do I create a teardrop in HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

How do I create a shape like this to display on a webpage?

I don't want to use **images** since they would get blurry on scaling

[image: Teardrop shape I need to make with HTML, CSS or SVG]

I tried with *CSS*:

```css
.tear {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tear">
</div>
```

That turned out really screwed.

And then I tried with SVG:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 100 100">
  <polygon points="50,0 100,70 50,100 0,70"/>
</svg>
```

It did get the shape, but the bottom part wasn't curved.

Is there a way to create this shape so it can be used in an HTML page?

Comment: You can create the shape you want here (and see the code by clicking one of the top buttons) : http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html#group

Comment: "I don't want to use images since they would get blurry on scaling", why are you scaling the image? They don't get blurry if you use `[srcset]` or the `<picture>` element. Better yet, just link to an svg image: `<img src="tear.svg" alt="Teardrop"/>`

Comment: @zzzzBov: Are you really recommending the [`picture`](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture) element? **No support** for IE, **no support** for early versions of Chrome, **no support** for safari. Should i continue?

Comment: @jbutler483, I recommend SVG for this case, but after that, [yes i'm recommending the `<picture>` element, along with Picturefill and an appropriate noscript fallback](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/).

Comment: @zzzzBov. `why are you scaling the image?` Well, the image can appear blurry without the dev scaling it. All you need for that is a browser zooming in. In my case, I have a HighDPI screen and plenty of blurry images. So, yeah, if you can avoid images using SVG, go for it.

Comment: Unicode solves it all... U+1F4A7 

Comment: @Thomas I see a square :/ http://i.stack.imgur.com/8fXMf.png

Comment: I think "droplet" is more appropriate to use for the title of this question?

Comment: @jbutler483 Safari and IE maybe, but who cares about early versions of Chrome? Especially since Chrome all but forces you to auto-update.

Comment: Semantically and practically, I think you should use an image for this. But, of course, you should *not* use a raster graphics image (not PNG, and definitely not JPG, God no), but a **vector graphics** image (that is, in practice, SVG).

Comment: There are benefits to both using a **css** and **svg** solution to achieve this shape.

Comment: @immibis older mobile phones may not get updates for browsers

Comment: Why not change the title of question to "drop of water"?

Comment: @SalmanA ... because a teardrop is the best description for this shape.  An actual drop of water (not on a surface) looks more like a jelly fish without tentacles... though most people do recognize a teardrop as the symbol for rain, this is a combination of tricks of the eye in fast motion of a rain drop interpolated to more observable slower flow of a teardrop

Answer (score 331, accepted):

### SVG approach:

You can achieve the double curve easily with an **inline SVG** and the `<path/>` element instead of the `<polygon/>` element which doesn't allow curved shapes.

The following example uses the `<path/>` element with:

- 2 [quadratic bezier curve commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) for the 2 top curves (lines beginning with `Q`)
- 1 [arc command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs) for the big bottom one (line beginning with `A`)

```html
<svg width="30%" viewbox="0 0 30 42">
  <path fill="transparent" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5"
        d="M15 3
           Q16.5 6.8 25 18
           A12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
           Q13.5 6.8 15 3z" />
</svg>
```

SVG is a great tool to make this kind of shapes with double curves. You can check this [post about double curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986125/double-curved-shape) with an SVG/CSS comparison. Some of the advantages of using SVG in this case are:

- Curve control
- Fill control (opacity, color)
- Stroke control (width, opacity, color)
- Amount of code
- Time to build and maintain the shape
- Scalable
- No HTTP request (if used inline like in the example)

---

**Browser support** for inline SVG goes back to Internet Explorer 9. See [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5) for more information.

Comment: it can reduce to: 
`<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 8 8" />
  <path d="M4 1L3 4A1.2 2 0 1 0 5 4"/>
</svg>`
 ... this will fill the area you give it, so it may make "fat" or "skinny" raindrops ... change to fixed height/width if necessary

Comment: @technosaurus the problem with reducing the number of commands in the `d="..."` attribute is that you don't have the double curve at the top of the drop anymore.

Comment: +1 because you should use SVG for this, not CSS. The CSS features you'd need to achieve it have about the same browser support as SVG so there's no advantage for CSS on that score. CSS can do shapes, but that's not what it's designed for; don't try to hammer in a nail with a screwdriver just for the sake of being clever when you can do it just as well with a tool designed for the job.

Comment: Even better: create a SVG file and use `<img />` in the hypertext document.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand that can be a good idea depending on the project but it adds a HTTP request which OP seems to want to avoid.

Answer (score 143):

### Basic Border-Radius

You can do this within CSS relatively easily using border-radius' and transforms. Your CSS was just a little bit out.

```css
.tear {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tear"></div>
```

### Advanced Border-Radius

This will be very similar to above but gives it a bit more shape.

```css
.tear {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 80% 0 55% 50% / 55% 0 80% 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tear"></div>
```

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't fully understand how it is the wrong tool, OP asked for a CSS or SVG solution and i came up with a CSS solution which fits the description as close as possible. Its lightweight and easy to modify.

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it state that CSS or SVG is a requirement. OP just posted his own attempts and asked "Is there anyway to create this shape so it can be used in a html page?" This answer suggests using CSS, which is not an appropriate way of generating what is semantically an image.

Comment: @zzzzBov Using CSS for images and sprites is common use. It is a very minimal piece of code to generate a generic "Image". I believe it is appropriate because it is usable within the questions spec of being usable on a web page.

Comment: @zzzzBov: CSS is perfectly fine for shapes. Who's to say what such shape is used for? *semantically an image* - OP has clearly stated they do not wish to use an image, otherwise why else would such a question be asked?

Comment: @jbutler483, "CSS is perfectly fine for shapes" no, it's awful. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*. It introduces all sorts of garbage in markup, and is a tedious mess to maintain. Images are much simpler to maintain as they are easily separated into their own individual self-contained file.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I'm guessing you're just one of those people who don't like shapes. That's fine. But I suppose you'd also use an image for the likes of a circle
just because it's more 'symantic' to do so. Whilst yes, for some items an image would be a smaller size than that of a css file, but in most cases, why add an extra http call when you can (quite happily) reduce this by using a short piece of css.

Comment: 'Garbage in the markup' occurs when you use bootstrap, or font awesome icons. Seriously, I think you're going a bit over the top for the likes of this when (quite obviously) this can be achieved using a border radius declaration. But hay, who's to tell you not to use images?

Comment: @zzzzBov: If it's decoration, it requires no markup at all; a `:before` or `:after` will do. If it's content ("semantically an image"), you can use an appropriate small image and alt text for fallback (CSS load failure, user settings, accessibility) and still use CSS to get something that scales well. SVG works as well, but it should only take two lines and an arc in a single stroked path to get the job done.

Comment: CSS can be a completely valid solution. @zzzzBov if a client demanded a non-standard li bullet i.e. checkmark, triangle, whatever, would you use an image? Or would you use :before? If you would use something else please leave a comment, I like learning new methods.

Comment: For CSS, it's amazing - but I prefer the SVG approach

Answer (score 89):

Your main issue with your CSS code was:

1. You used a different height than width
2. You haven't rotated the correct angle size

So, by 'fixing' these issues, you would generate:

```css
.tear {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
/***for demo only***/

.tear {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tear">
</div>
```

*Please also note to save on CSS length, you could re-write your border-radius properties to:*

```
border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
```

---

this could be enhanced with pseudo elements [**as shown in this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/h96rnho2/1/)

## Alternatives

I found [this](http://codepen.io/VinayChalluru/pen/LKphA) by **Vinay Challuru** on codepen.

Please note that with the logic here, I was able to create the **SVG** to nearly any possible build shape/etc. For example, a quick output was:

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 400 400'>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-width="5" d="M200,40 C200,115 280,180 280,240 A80,80,0 0,1,120,240 C120,180 200,115 200,40" stroke-linejoin='miter'></path>
</svg>
```

It's using an SVG and allows you to alter the shape in multiple ways, having the ability to alter its shape to the desired result:

```js
var SVG = function() {
  this.element = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
  this.namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  this.width = 400;
  this.height = 400;
}

/****Let's initialise our SVG ready to draw our shape****/
var svg = new SVG();

/****This sets up the user interface - we've included the script for this as an external library for the codepen****/
var gui = new dat.GUI();

/****Here's where the code to create the shape begins!****/
var Teardrop = function() {
  this.x = svg.width * 0.5;
  this.y = svg.height * 0.1;
  this.width = svg.width * 0.4;
  this.triangleHeight = svg.height * 0.5;
  this.yCP1 = svg.height * 0.2;
  this.yCP2 = svg.height * 0.45;
  this.element = null;
  this.ctrlPoints = [];
  this.anchors = [];
  this.fill = "none";
  this.stroke = "#333";
  this.strokeWidth = 2;
  this.showCtrlPoints = true;
  this.init();
}

Teardrop.prototype.init = function() {
  this.element = document.createElementNS(svg.namespace, "path");
  svg.element.appendChild(this.element);
  this.element.setAttribute("fill", this.fill);
  this.element.setAttribute("stroke", this.stroke);
  this.element.setAttribute("stroke-width", this.strokeWidth);

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    this.ctrlPoints.push(document.createElementNS(svg.namespace, "circle"));
    svg.element.appendChild(this.ctrlPoints[i]);

    this.ctrlPoints[i].setAttribute("fill", this.fill);
    this.ctrlPoints[i].setAttribute("stroke", 'red');
    this.ctrlPoints[i].setAttribute("stroke-width", 1);


    this.anchors.push(document.createElementNS(svg.namespace, "line"));
    svg.element.appendChild(this.anchors[i]);

    this.anchors[i].setAttribute("stroke-width", 1);
    this.anchors[i].setAttribute("stroke", this.stroke);
    this.anchors[i].setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", "3,2");
  }

  this.draw();
}

Teardrop.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.radius = this.width / 2;
  path = [
    "M", this.x, ",", this.y,
    "C", this.x, ",", this.yCP1, " ", this.x + this.width / 2, ",", this.yCP2, " ", this.x + this.width / 2, ",", this.y + this.triangleHeight,
    "A", this.radius, ",", this.radius, ",", "0 0,1,", this.x - this.width / 2, ",", this.y + this.triangleHeight,
    "C", this.x - this.width / 2, ",", this.yCP2, " ", this.x, ",", this.yCP1, " ", this.x, ",", this.y
  ];
  this.element.setAttribute("d", path.join(""));

  cpCoords = [];
  cpCoords[0] = [this.x, this.yCP1];
  cpCoords[1] = [this.x - this.width / 2, this.yCP2];
  cpCoords[2] = [this.x + this.width / 2, this.yCP2];

  anchorCoords = [];
  anchorCoords[0] = [this.x, this.y];
  anchorCoords[1] = [this.x - this.width / 2, this.y + this.triangleHeight];
  anchorCoords[2] = [this.x + this.width / 2, this.y + this.triangleHeight];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    this.ctrlPoints[i].setAttribute("cx", cpCoords[i][0]);
    this.ctrlPoints[i].setAttribute("cy", cpCoords[i][1]);

    this.anchors[i].setAttribute("x1", cpCoords[i][0]);
    this.anchors[i].setAttribute("x2", anchorCoords[i][0]);
    this.anchors[i].setAttribute("y1", cpCoords[i][1]);
    this.anchors[i].setAttribute("y2", anchorCoords[i][1]);

    if (this.showCtrlPoints) {
      this.ctrlPoints[i].setAttribute("r", 2);
      this.anchors[i].setAttribute("stroke-width", 1);
    } else {
      this.ctrlPoints[i].setAttribute("r", 0);
      this.anchors[i].setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);
    }
  }
}

var teardrop = new Teardrop();

gui.add(teardrop, 'triangleHeight', 0, svg.height * 0.75);
gui.add(teardrop, 'width', 0, 200);
gui.add(teardrop, 'yCP1', 0, svg.height);
gui.add(teardrop, 'yCP2', 0, svg.height);
gui.add(teardrop, 'showCtrlPoints', 0, svg.height);

for (var i in gui.__controllers) {
  gui.__controllers[i].onChange(function() {
    teardrop.draw();
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('http://unitedshapes.com/images/graph-paper/graph-paper.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<svg width='400px' height='400px'></svg>
```

> **Disclaimer** I did not write the above pen, only sourced it.

---

## CSS Version

Although this is far from complete, you may also be able to generate this shape using CSS.

```css
.tear{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 29%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:120px;
    position:relative;
}
.tear:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:-70%;left:0%;
    height:100%;width:50%;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at -50% -50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 76%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
.tear:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:-70%;left:50%;
    height:100%;width:50%;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 150% -50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 76%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="tear"></div>
```

## SVG Version

I should know that SVG should be at the top of this answer, however, I like a challenge and so here is an attempt with SVG.

```css
svg {
  height: 300px;
}
svg path {
  fill: tomato;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <path d="M49.015,0.803
    c-0.133-1.071-1.896-1.071-2.029,0
    C42.57,36.344,20,43.666,20,68.367   
    C20,83.627,32.816,96,48,96
    s28-12.373,28-27.633
    C76,43.666,53.43,36.344,49.015,0.803z 
    M44.751,40.09   
    c-0.297,1.095-0.615,2.223-0.942,3.386
    c-2.007,7.123-4.281,15.195-4.281,24.537
    c0,5.055-2.988,6.854-5.784,6.854   
    c-3.189,0-5.782-2.616-5.782-5.831
    c0-11.034,5.315-18.243,10.005-24.604
    c1.469-1.991,2.855-3.873,3.983-5.749   
    c0.516-0.856,1.903-0.82,2.533,0.029
    C44.781,39.116,44.879,39.619,44.751,40.09z"/>


</svg>
```

Altering the `path` values, you would be able to alter the shape of your teardrop design.

Comment: These all seem very... verbose. The js solution is particularly absurd.

Comment: @egid: I did state in my answer that I did not create the js version. Also note the js version is allowing you to alter the shape at run time

Answer (score 59):

IMO this shape requires **smooth curve-to** beziers to ensure continuity of the curve.

### The Drop in question :

For the drop in question,

- smooth curves can't be used, as control points wont be of same length. But we still need to make the control points lie exactly opposite (180 deg) to the previous control points, **to ensure full continuity of curve** The picture given below illustrates this point :

[image]
**Note**: Red and blue curves are two different quadratic curves.

- `stroke-linejoin="miter"`, for the pointed top part.
- AS this shape only uses successive **`c`** commands, we can omit it.

**Here's the final snippet:**

```html
<svg height="300px" width="300px" viewBox="0 0 12 16">
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linejoin="miter" 
        d="M 6 1 c -2 3 -5 5 -5 9
           0 7 10 7 10 0 
           0 -4 -3 -6 -5 -9z" />
</svg>
```

**TBH though**, accepted answer's curves are not quite continuous.

---

### For IE 5-8 (VML)

Only works in IE 5-8. **VML** uses different commands than **SVG**. Eg. it uses **v for relative cubic beziers**.

**Note:** This snippet won't run in IE 5-8 too. You need to create an html file and run it directly in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <style> v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); }

    </style >
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:240; height:320;">
        <v:shape coordorigin="0 0" coordsize="12 16" fillcolor="white" strokecolor="black" strokewidth="1"
            strokeweight="5" style="width:240; height:320" 
            path="M 6 1 v -2 3 -5 5 -5 9
           0 7 10 7 10 0 
           0 -4 -3 -6 -5 -9 x e">
        </v:shape>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "smooth curves can't be used, as control points wont be of same length." Doesn't "smooth" just mean that the tangent handles (control points) sit on a straight line? Why do they have to be of the same length?

Comment: @NiccoloM. In svg, smooth curve (T and S commands) means that the handle is symmetrically opposite, as well as **equal to previous handle's length**. In normal language, smooth curve might mean different handle lengths, but in svg, the length also is equal to previous curves handle :)

Answer (score 42):

Or if your viewers' font supports it, use the Unicode characters

## DROPLET:  (`&#128167;`)

or

## BLACK DROPLET:  (`&#127778;`)

Scale accordingly!

Comment: You could use this with @font-face, but then you have a font file to keep in the right place and such.

Comment: SVG and a dedicated Unicode symbol like this is good. CSS for this is bad. PNG is okay, but not perfect since it is raster graphics. JPG is extremely bad, so bad that I would get nightmares if I saw it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand a 20x20 PNG would scale worst than a 200x200 JPG. And, with the same size, an uncompressed JPG is equivalent to a PNG. They are both raster and they suffer from the same issues.

Comment: @nico: In theory, yes, you can use JPG with zero compression. But the Internet is full of disasters like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number#/media/File:Atomic_number_depiction.jpg

Answer (score 29):

### HTML Canvas

This is an option uncovered in this thread so far. The commands used for Canvas drawings are very similar to SVG (and web-tiki deserves the credits for the base idea used in this answer).

The shape in question can be created either using canvas' own curve commands (Quadratic or Bezier) or the Path API. The answer contains examples for all three methods.

The browser support for Canvas is [quite good](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas).

---

#### Using Quadratic Curves

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.moveTo(120, 20);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(117.5, 30, 148, 68);
    ctx.arc(120, 88, 34.5, 5.75, 3.66, false);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(117.5, 35, 120, 20);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#77CCEE'
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Below is an **advanced version** with gradient fill and shadows. I have also included a `hover` effect on the shape to illustrate one drawback of Canvas when compared to SVG. Canvas is raster (pixel) based and hence would look blurred/pixelated when scaled beyond a certain point. The only solution to that would be to repaint the shape on every browser resize which is an overhead.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var lineargradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(135, 95, 1, 135, 95, 10);
    lineargradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');
    lineargradient.addColorStop(1, '#77CCEE');      
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.moveTo(120, 20);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(117.5, 30, 148, 68);
    ctx.arc(120, 88, 34.5, 5.75, 3.66, false);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(117.5, 35, 120, 20);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#333';
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.fillStyle = lineargradient;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)";      
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}


/* Just for demo */

body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}

canvas{
  transition: all 1s;
}

canvas:hover{
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

---

#### Using Bezier Curves

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var lineargradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(135, 95, 1, 135, 95, 10);
    lineargradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');
    lineargradient.addColorStop(1, '#77CCEE');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.arc(120, 88, 35, 5.74, 3.66, false);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(100, 55, 122, 27.5, 120, 20);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(122, 27.5, 121, 31.5, 150, 70);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(109,195,250,0.2)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = lineargradient;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  margin: 75px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' height='300' width='300'></canvas>
```

#### Using Path API

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    var p = new Path2D("M120 20 Q117.5 30 146 68 A34 34 0 1 1 92 68 Q117.5 35 120 20z");
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#77CCEE'
    ctx.stroke(p);
    ctx.fill(p);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

<sup>**Note:** As mentioned in my answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458239/draw-path-in-canvas-with-svg-path-data-svg-paths-to-canvas-paths/30830108#30830108), the Path API is not yet supported by IE and Safari.</sup>

---

**Further reading:**

- [7 Reasons to Consider SVGs Instead of Canvas](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-consider-svgs-instead-of-canvas/)
- [HTML5 Canvas vs. SVG: Choose the Best Tool for the Job](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/html5-canvas-vs.-svg-choose-the-best-tool-for-the-job.html)
- [What is the difference between SVG and HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996374/what-is-the-difference-between-svg-and-html5-canvas)

Comment: I dont see how svg is better option always. it certainly is better option in many cases like this one. But canvas has its own pros. Nice answer. from your answer i can make out that, it certainly is a lot easier to use SVG!

Comment: Yeah @TimKrul, its easier to write/use SVG. Canvas has its own pros but from whatever I read it is not too advantageous when using for simple logo like shapes primarily because it is raster based unlike SVG.

Answer (score 28):

I'd personally use an SVG for this. You can create SVGs in most vector graphics software. I'd recommend:

- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)
- [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/)
- Adobe Illustrator

I have made one below that is a tracing of your shape in Illustrator.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="223.14px" height="319.008px" viewBox="0 0 223.14 319.008" enable-background="new 0 0 223.14 319.008" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="12" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M111.57,13.291c0,0,57.179,86.984,72.719,108.819
     c30.359,42.66,41.005,114.694,1.626,154.074c-20.464,20.463-47.533,30.293-74.344,29.488h-0.002
     c-26.811,0.805-53.88-9.025-74.344-29.488C-2.154,236.804,8.492,164.77,38.851,122.11C54.391,100.275,111.57,13.291,111.57,13.291z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 25):

I also found [this](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/wshza) on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) made by user [Ana Tudor](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/) using CSS and the `box-shadow` style and parametric equations. Very simple, very little code. And many [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) support the CSS3 Box-shadow style:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.tear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -0.125em;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0em -5em red, 0.00118em -4.97592em #ff1800, 0.00937em -4.90393em #ff3000, 0.03125em -4.7847em #ff4800, 0.07283em -4.6194em #ff6000, 0.13915em -4.40961em #ff7800, 0.23408em -4.15735em #ff8f00, 0.36em -3.86505em #ffa700, 0.51777em -3.53553em #ffbf00, 0.70654em -3.17197em gold, 0.92382em -2.77785em #ffef00, 1.16547em -2.35698em #f7ff00, 1.42582em -1.91342em #dfff00, 1.69789em -1.45142em #c7ff00, 1.97361em -0.97545em #afff00, 2.2441em -0.49009em #97ff00, 2.5em 0.0em #80ff00, 2.73182em 0.49009em #68ff00, 2.93032em 0.97545em #50ff00, 3.08681em 1.45142em #38ff00, 3.19358em 1.91342em #20ff00, 3.24414em 2.35698em #08ff00, 3.23352em 2.77785em #00ff10, 3.15851em 3.17197em #00ff28, 3.01777em 3.53553em #00ff40, 2.81196em 3.86505em #00ff58, 2.54377em 4.15735em #00ff70, 2.21783em 4.40961em #00ff87, 1.84059em 4.6194em #00ff9f, 1.42017em 4.7847em #00ffb7, 0.96608em 4.90393em #00ffcf, 0.48891em 4.97592em #00ffe7, 0.0em 5em cyan, -0.48891em 4.97592em #00e7ff, -0.96608em 4.90393em #00cfff, -1.42017em 4.7847em #00b7ff, -1.84059em 4.6194em #009fff, -2.21783em 4.40961em #0087ff, -2.54377em 4.15735em #0070ff, -2.81196em 3.86505em #0058ff, -3.01777em 3.53553em #0040ff, -3.15851em 3.17197em #0028ff, -3.23352em 2.77785em #0010ff, -3.24414em 2.35698em #0800ff, -3.19358em 1.91342em #2000ff, -3.08681em 1.45142em #3800ff, -2.93032em 0.97545em #5000ff, -2.73182em 0.49009em #6800ff, -2.5em 0.0em #7f00ff, -2.2441em -0.49009em #9700ff, -1.97361em -0.97545em #af00ff, -1.69789em -1.45142em #c700ff, -1.42582em -1.91342em #df00ff, -1.16547em -2.35698em #f700ff, -0.92382em -2.77785em #ff00ef, -0.70654em -3.17197em #ff00d7, -0.51777em -3.53553em #ff00bf, -0.36em -3.86505em #ff00a7, -0.23408em -4.15735em #ff008f, -0.13915em -4.40961em #ff0078, -0.07283em -4.6194em #ff0060, -0.03125em -4.7847em #ff0048, -0.00937em -4.90393em #ff0030, -0.00118em -4.97592em #ff0018;
}
```

```html
<div class="tear"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't resemble the kind of teardrop being asked for, though.

Answer (score 20):

### CSS Version

As there are a fair few answers here I thought why not add to it with another method. This is using both **HTML** and **CSS** to create the teardrop.

This will allow you to change the colour of the border and background of the teardrop and also re-size the top part of it.

Using a single `div` we can create a circle with `border` and `border-radius`. Then using pseudo elements (`:before` & `:after`) we create a [CSS triangle](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh) <sup>[more here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)</sup>, this will act as the tip of the teardrop. Using the `:before` as the border we place `:after` on top with a smaller size and the desired background colour.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
div:before {
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 104px solid black;
  top: -75px;
}
div:after {
  border-left: 46px solid transparent;
  border-right: 46px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 96px solid #fff;
  top: -66px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Here is a demo of the teardrop with a background colour

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: red;
  margin: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
div:before {
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid black;
  top: -70px;
}
div:after {
  border-left: 46px solid transparent;
  border-right: 46px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 96px solid red;
  top: -66px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

It is as simple as putting a background colour onto the `div` and changing `:after` `bottom-border` colour to the same. To change the border you will need to change `div` border colour and `:before` background colour too.

Comment: Ruddy the pen is missing a background color value.

Comment: @Persijn Harry said something in chat and I was looking at it on that pen forgetting it auto saves every now and then. Haha, I will put it back the way it was. Done.

Answer (score 17):

It is quite easy to do this with SVG by just using an image conversion resource such as http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg, which was used to create the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="213.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 213.000000 300.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.12, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2015
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,300.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M1035 2944 c-143 -250 -231 -380 -508 -752 -347 -465 -432 -616 -493
-882 -91 -394 10 -753 285 -1013 508 -479 1334 -361 1677 240 126 221 165 494
105 726 -66 254 -178 452 -609 1076 -96 140 -226 335 -288 435 -155 249 -135
229 -169 170z m85 -212 c40 -69 192 -298 543 -818 268 -396 354 -593 364 -835
12 -281 -82 -509 -296 -714 -103 -99 -236 -173 -396 -221 -82 -25 -105 -27
-260 -28 -148 -1 -181 2 -255 22 -348 96 -611 357 -691 689 -41 167 -25 392
41 587 62 185 154 334 444 716 177 235 320 444 402 592 27 49 51 88 54 88 3 0
25 -35 50 -78z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Persijn Yes, read the top: "which was used to create the following"

Comment: @Persijn why do you keep asking copied from some editor? Svg is svg , you can use whichever tool you want to create one.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal this is a coding site, so I prefer solutions made by hand/coded.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: 'editors' as you like to call them, add extra 'fluff' to declarations. For example, `300.000000pt` and metadata that's not *really* needed

Comment: @Persijn what do you mean by hand/coded. Someone just made/hand/coded illustrator to just ease their coding tasks, and it still produces the same thing. Then again when you're using svg in browser, why don't you yourself hand/code it using assembly language? and why stop at assembly , hand/code it using wires or just draw it yourself. This is not a reason that I was expecting.

Comment: @jbutler483 yes and they can be trimmed out. There are many tools that do that for you , here's one for you https://github.com/svg/svgo

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-and-designs

Comment: @persijn this answer provides the svg paths needed. i really have no clue what your objection is.

Answer (score 10):

Here are four progressively simpler SVG teardrop shapes:

[image]

```html
<svg viewbox="-20 -20 180 180">
  <g stroke="black" fill="none">
    
    <path transform="translate(0)"
     d="M   0  0
        C   0 10  10 17  10 27
        C  10 40 -10 40 -10 27
        C -10 17   0 10   0  0
        Z"/>

    <path transform="translate(40)"
     d="M   0  0
        C   0 16  15 25   5 34
        Q   0 38         -5 34
        C -15 25   0 16   0  0
        Z"/>
    
    <path transform="translate(80)"
     d="M   0  0
        C   0 10  18 36   0 36
        S          0 10   0  0
        Z"/>

    <path transform="translate(120)"
     d="M   0  0
        Q  18 36   0 36
        T          0  0
        Z"/>
    
    
    
    
    <g stroke-width="0.25" stroke="red">
      <g transform="translate(0)">
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="0" />
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="10"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="10"  cy="17"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="10"  cy="27"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="10"  cy="40"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="-10" cy="40"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="-10" cy="27"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="-10" cy="17"/>
        <line x1="0"   y1="0"  x2="0"   y2="10"/>
        <line x1="10"  y1="17" x2="10"  y2="40"/>
        <line x1="-10" y1="40" x2="-10" y2="17"/>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(40)">
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="0" />
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="16"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="15"  cy="25"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="5"   cy="34"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="38"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="-5"  cy="34"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="-15" cy="25"/>
        <line x1="0"  y1="0"  x2="0"   y2="16"/>
        <line x1="15" y1="25" x2="0"   y2="38"/>
        <line x1="0"  y1="38" x2="-15" y2="25"/>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(80)">
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="0" />
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="10"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="18"  cy="36"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="36"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="-18" cy="36" stroke="gray"/>
        <line x1="0"  y1="0"  x2="0"   y2="10"/>
        <line x1="18" y1="36" x2="0"   y2="36"/>
        <line x1="0"  y1="36" x2="-18" y2="36" stroke="gray" stroke-dasharray="0.5"/>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(120)">
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="0" />
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="18"  cy="36"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="0"   cy="36"/>
        <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="-18" cy="36" stroke="gray"/>
        <line x1="18" y1="36" x2="0"   y2="36"/>
        <line x1="0"  y1="36" x2="-18" y2="36" stroke="gray" stroke-dasharray="0.5"/>
      </g>
    </g>    
  </g>
  <g font-size="6" transform="translate(-1.5,-4)">
    <text x="-10" y="-8"># of unique points:</text>
    <text transform="translate(  0)">8</text>
    <text transform="translate( 40)">7</text>
    <text transform="translate( 80)">4</text>
    <text transform="translate(120)">3</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```