# How can we make this shape using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can we make this shape using CSS?

[image]

I'm able to write the below code using CSS but the shape generated output is a bit off. Can we do that using CSS?

```css
.btn-arrow {
  width: 15px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  border-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-arrow:after,
.btn-arrow:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.btn-arrow:after {
  border-right-color: white;
  border-width: 12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.btn-arrow:before {
  border-right-color: red;
  border-width: 14px;
  margin-top: -14px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-arrow"></div>
```

Comment: This would be much easier with SVG rather than HTML and CSS

Comment: The rounding in your shape goes on for more than 180 degrees, so you can’t expect to achieve that with two border-radius that cover/span an exact 90 degree section each. You would have to start with a fully rounded element, and then overlap parts of it with the actual “right angle/straight edge” shape ... which means, if you need it to be transparent/work on multi-color backgrounds, this is pretty much out right away.

Comment: Thanks guys for the direction. I'll go with SVG

Comment: I have a solution with CSS, if you give me some time to construct it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711203/how-do-i-create-a-teardrop-in-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS you can achieve that.

Just create `::after` and `::before` pseudoelements and the main box rotate 45 degrees. You can adjust the degrees on the `linear-gradient` part instead of "to right" sentence.

This trick is necessary because `border-image` and `border-radius` can't live both on the same element.

You can see more about this:

- [Possible to use border-radius together with a border-image which has a gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient#29223812)
- https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

```css
.shape {
  position:relative;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.shape::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px; 
    bottom: -8px;
    left: -8px; 
    right: -8px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fe3870, #fc5d3e);
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
}
.shape::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px; 
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 8px; 
    right: 8px;
    background: white;
    content: '';
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
</div>
```

Comment: i think the difficult part is not only the shape but the gradient of the shape

Comment: I am using the `border-image` property but seems to be incompatible with border radius, so I achieved without background. I will following try.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I achieved the white background. Just with `::after` and `::before`. I will explain on post.

Comment: i understand what you ahve done ;) but now you are missing the transparent part ... not sure if the OP need it or not

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm. Thanks for the solution but more importantly for pointing in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

One of many possible solutions in just CSS:

This solution only requires one pseudo element.

```css
.btn-arrow {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(232,51,105,1) 0%,rgba(235,94,67,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
}

.btn-arrow::after {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-arrow"></div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. This is exactly I wanted but I learned this new thing. Thanks for the answer & the time

Answer (score -2):

Adjust the CSS to look like this

```
.btn-arrow {
      width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-arrow:after,
.btn-arrow:before {
  right: calc(100% - 6px);
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.btn-arrow:after {
  border-right-color: white;
  border-width: 12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.btn-arrow:before {
  border-right-color: red;
  border-width: 14px;
  margin-top: -14px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not the exact design/shape I want. Other answer helped but thanks for the time