# How to make a tall teardrop shape in css

Tags: css

In the image below there is a blue long teardrop above each rocket. I'm trying to figure out how to do that in CSS with `border-radius`.

Is this possible (with or without `border-radius`)?

[image]

Comment: Why with `border-radius`?

Comment: Its the only way I thought of to get the rounded taper. Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a teardrop in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711203/how-do-i-create-a-teardrop-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents (but I believe it can be done in a better way), but with this way you can modify the line `height` for every rocket. Basically the top part is a long triangle, and the bottom part is a circle:

```css
.teardrop {
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 150px 5px; /* 150px is the line height */
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}

.teardrop::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="teardrop">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

---

Using only one `div`:

```css
.teardrop {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 150px 5px; /* 150px is the line height */
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}

.teardrop::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -155px; /* 150 + height/2 */
  right: -5px; /* width/2 */
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="teardrop"></div>
```

Comment: This is great. The only thing that would make it better is if the height could be based on the height of `.teardrop`. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Justin808 [here's a solution using only one `div`](https://jsfiddle.net/e5mnj0a1/1).