# why array is not passing all the values js

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `Contorno`

```
CONTORNO = [{
    tipo: "m",
    x: [0, 0]
  },
  {
    tipo: "l",
    x: [0.06, 0],
    x: [0.06, 0.04],
    x: [0.14, 0.04],
    x: [0.14, 0],
    x: [0.24, 0],
    x: [0.24, 0.04],
    x: [0.34, 0.04],
    x: [0.34, 0],
    x: [0.44, 0],
    x: [0.44, 0.04],
    x: [0.54, 0.04],
    x: [0.54, 0],
    x: [0.64, 0],
    x: [0.64, 0.04],
    x: [0.74, 0.04],
    x: [0.74, 0],
    x: [0.8, 0],
    x: [0.8, 1],
    x: [0.40, 0.55],
    x: [0, 1]
  }

]
```

and then I call in the function  `caminho()` defined here:

```
function caminho(c, a) {
  c.beginPath();
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   if (a[i].tipo === "m") {
    c.moveTo(a[i].x[0], a[i].x[1]);
    }else if (a[i].tipo === "l") {
      c.lineTo(a[i].x[0], a[i].x[1]);
   }
  }

 }
```

the problem is when I call him

```
var c = document.getElementById("acanvas").getContext("2d");
caminho(c,CONTORNO);
```

It is not drawing all the points but just one, I mean it is not passing all points in for loop.

What is the problem?

Comment: what are `c`, `enter()` and `leave()`?

Comment: are functions transform the points but they are not important for here, I wiil remove them. Removed

Comment: There is still one thing missing: `c`

Comment: c is the context of acanvas

Comment: objects `{}` can't have the same property more than once. For example `{a:1, a:2}` becomes `{a:2}`

Comment: @Slai what do you suggest if i want have the struct above where I have a character and in that character have a lot of coordenates.

Comment: idk .. array of arrays `x: [[1,2], [3,4]]`, or something easier like SVG path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458239/draw-path-in-canvas-with-svg-path-data-svg-paths-to-canvas-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned you can't have duplicate keys in an object. Best way is to restructure your data. For example, use an array containing all the positions.

Here's a code that shows how to select the positions from it, if you want to access all of the positions of `typo` equal `l`. Use:

```js
CONTORNO = 
[
  {
    tipo: "m",
    pos: [ [0, 0] ]
  },
  {
    tipo: "l",
    pos: [ [0.06, 0], [0.06, 0.04], [0.14, 0.04], [0.14, 0], [0.24, 0], [0.24, 0.04], [0.34, 0.04], [0.34, 0], [0.44, 0], [0.44, 0.04], [0.54, 0.04], [0.54, 0], [0.64, 0], [0.64, 0.04], [0.74, 0.04], [0.74, 0], [0.8, 0], [0.8, 1], [0.40, 0.55], [0, 1] ]
  }
]

function caminho(c, a) {
  c.beginPath();
  a.forEach(function(value, i) {
    if (value.tipo === "m") {
      c.moveTo(value.pos[i][0], value.pos[i][1]);
    } else if (value.tipo === "l") {
      value.pos.forEach(function(pos, j) {
        c.lineTo(pos[0], pos[1]);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The inside `.forEach()` will loop through the array of positions.

Comment: It is incrementing yes, do you want to access all of the positions? or only the first under with typo equal to `l`?

Comment: i want to acess all the positions, yes. but is not doing that, just the first position of l.

Answer (score 0):

Your object elements have duplicate `x` keys.

`a[i].x[0]` appears to be the final `x` key that you specify, which is `[0,1]`.

You have:

```
{
  tipo: "l",
  x: [2 d array],
  x: [2 d array]
}
```

Which isn't really legal.

You probably want:

```
{
  tipo: "l",
  x: [...a bunch of two dimensional arrays...]
}
```

Comment: so I can have like this: {tipo: "l", x:[0,0,1,2...] , where (0,0) and (1,2) are differents coordenates?

Comment: or I put x:[[x,y],[x1,y2]...] instead of [x1,y1,x2,y2..]?

Comment: Your second comment is likely correct.  x:[ [0.06, 0.0], [0.06, 0.04] ... ]